# Update Homebrew casks versions

Tags: macos, version, homebrew, upgrade, homebrew-cask

I know, that Homebrew doesn't upgrade casks with auto-update (without force). So eventually, software versions, actually installed, and tracked by Homebrew, become different. For example:

```sh
$ brew cask outdated --greedy
firefox (79.0) != 80.0
google-chrome (84.0.4147.105) != 85.0.4183.83
microsoft-edge (84.0.522.48) != 85.0.564.41
```

Firefox, Chrome and Edge auto-updates themselves and actually has latest versions. But Homebrew doesn't know about it.

So, is there a way to tell Homebrew, that some cask is the latest version already, *without reinstalling cask with brew*? Just update record in Homebrew database (or whatever brew stores casks' versions in).

Comment: Can you submit this into `https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask`, seems interesting.

Comment: Ok, [submitted](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/88440). I thought GitHub is for issues, and SO is for QA :) But maybe this looks like feature request, after all.

Comment: SO is actually not the official forum, homebrew has a dedicated one, https://discourse.brew.sh.

Comment: I just feel like this might be suitable for github, I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there is no official way to do it.

Following [related GitHub conversation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/88440) I wrote [my own script](https://gist.github.com/yumauri/1915426eff7c07990fbc802376db8f30) to fulfil my obsession of checking versions :)

If anyone wants to use it — **use it on your own risk, you will get no support for issues that arise from this approach**. Also, I tried to make neat and robust script, which backups data, but if script will remove any of your data — *I'm not responsible for that*. I encourage you to read the script and understand, what it is doing.